# CSS position: relative; children do not ignore each other

Tags: html, css

I always used float. Recognized maybe its not the best way to go. Trying around with position relative.
why the children of myDiv do not ignore each others top ? Because its not inline-block ?

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="myDiv1"></div>
    <div class="myDiv2"></div>
    <div class="myDiv3"></div>
    <div class="myDiv4"></div>
</div>

.myDiv
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.myDiv1
{
    background-color: green;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

.myDiv2
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 30px;
}

.myDiv3
{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50px;
}

.myDiv4
{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 70px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VLk6m/2/

Comment: Really depends on what you want to achieve ^_^ There is nothing really wrong with using float. But otherwise you are right ... if you want the divs to be in one line the alternative is to make them inline-blocks (if so you need to be aware of some intrinsic properties of such elements, e.g. that the spaces between them are rendered as inline)

Answer (score 1):

That is expected behavior.  [See the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> Lay out all elements as though the element were not positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have been had it not been positioned).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here, but if you want them to all be on the same row you'll either need to use float or set the `display` to `inline-block`.  Otherwise, when it's `display: block`, it takes up the whole "row" and it doesn't know you want them to be on the same row.